# Weight tracking app

Tags: applications

I'm looking for an app to help me track my weight. Ideally, I would tell it my weight each day (and perhaps my age and height), and after a while I could use it so plot a graph of my progress but also get extra informative statistics.

I've seen a lot of health related apps on the market, but a lot of them are payed and come with tons of extra features. I don't need diet guidance, exercise reminders, etc. I just need something to track my weight, preferably free.

Thanks

Comment: What apps have you already tried?

Comment: @aleveret: simple weight loss resolution (which is too simple), and diet 2go (which has a lot of stuff I don't use and doesn't seem to have graphing).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See this:

http://www.appbrain.com/app/lifetracking/com.lifetracking

LifeTracking application allows you to track any value that is important to you like your weight, blood pressure, or number of pushups you do a day, as well as any time-consuming activities like sleeping, working, watching TV, etc. You can also graph the data to see it visually and use the application to analyze it.
The goal of the application is to help you know yourself and your schedule better. Hopefully, when you graph things side-by-side you'll understand yourself and your life bette

Comment: Took me a while to test it, but it's exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

**[Weigh Weight Lite](http://www.appbrain.com/app/weigh-weight-lite/junsuke.life.weighweight)** did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

[MyWeigth](http://www.mremedy.com/products/myWeight.php) is a promising app for that purpose, but not yet released to android.

> myWeight puts the retina display to work with beatuiful hi-resolution graphics. Interactive controls and dials will have you looking forward to tracking your weight each day. Our elegant Sync feature will guarantee your data is safe and accessable anywhere. Available now in the iTunes App Store and soon to the Android market.

Answer (score -1):

FatSecret has a [Calorie Counter App](http://www.fatsecret.com/connected/android) that keeps track of your weight.  You can also use it to keep track of calories consumed and exercise on a daily basis.  Information can be backed up to the FatSecret site online if you choose to do so.

Comment: And the reason for a downvote is?

Comment: Maybe they don't like that app.